# CSS Gradient Poor Quality

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

**Hello guys,**
You can check out my preloader here: http://apesdesk.apespark.com/ *(Press **ESC** as soon as you open the page in order to stop loading the rest of the website and see the loader as much time as you need)*

When you do so, you'll see the problem with the quality of the background linear gradient quality. The GIFs quality is way better than the CSS's gradient quality. I have no idea why this is caused and how I should fix it. Normally CSS shouldn't have those issues as it's actually computing the gradient, it's not an image, etc. to have lossless quality.

**Regards,

Denis Saidov

ApesPark**

P.S. I've temporary commented everything else and made the loader to loop infinitely.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. I would suggest using a pseudo element to cover either the top or bottom of the page instead if you can't get the gradient to work.

E.g: 
#preloader{background-color: #fff;}
#preloader::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0:
  height: 50%;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #477FE7;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: @ConorLuddy It did the job. Please, feel free to post this as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to tag your name but it won't work. As mentioned in my comment -

I'm getting the same issue. For a workaround solution I would suggest using a pseudo element to cover either the top or bottom of the page instead.

E.g.

```
 #preloader {
  background-color: #fff;
 } 

 #preloader::before { 
  position:  absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0: 
  height: 50%; 
  right: 0;
  background-color: #477FE7; 
  z-index: 0; 
 }
```

Cheers,
Conor